# Prisma - How to retrieve data from indirect relation?

Tags: typescript, schema, relational-database, prisma

I've started to work with Prisma and have built [this given schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0USs.png) for a boot camp project, which is working fine.

I've been able to work with relations and nested fields for straightforward Prima's CRUD operations.

But now I'm trying to, in a single call (of `prisma.term.findMany`), get data in this model:

```
data = {
    terms: [{id, name, 
        disciplines: [{id, name, 
            categories: [{id, name, 
                tests: [{id, name, pdfUrl, teacher}]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Right now, I can kind of do that following those relations: terms > disciplines > disciplines teachers > tests > categories. Then, I'm using another function just to remodel this object and return to the desired model.

The challenge is that there is no direct relation between disciplines and categories in the schema.

Is it possible to return this data with 1 access, using select/include?

Answer (score 0):

Without a relation between disciplines and categories, it is not possible to retrieve everything in one query without using [`$queryRaw`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw).